# JButton repeating action depending on how many times pressed

Tags: java, jbutton

I'm building a simple program in Java which gets a balance (mine is set to $8000). I want to deposit money into that so I have a UI with 0-9 buttons, a textarea and a deposit button, so if the user wanted to deposit $100 he would press 1 once then 0 twice. All that works and it deposits for the first time, but the second time it deposits the double amount of money. If I press my deposit button 10 times and select $1 then press enter it deposits $10. I think the structure of my btn action listener might be wrong.

Any ideas?

**Code:**

```
btnDeposit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label1.setText("Deposit: How much would you like to deposit?");
        btnWithdraw.setEnabled(false);
        btnBalance.setEnabled(false);

        btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //convert text area into double
                double depositNumber = Double.parseDouble(ta.getText());
                sav.deposit(depositNumber);
                btnWithdraw.setEnabled(true);
                btnBalance.setEnabled(true);
            }

        });

    }
});
```

My deposit function is:

```
public void deposit(double depositAmount) {
    balance += depositAmount;
    System.out.println("Your updated balance is: " + balance);
}
```

I also noticed that it doesn't go back to where it started, if I keep clicking on Enter it keeps adding and adding...

Button that clear my text area:

```
btnClear.addActionListener(new new ActionListener(){ 
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  ta.setText("");
}
});
```

Comment: Do you clear the textfield?

Comment: Yes,if I deposit $1, click on enter, then clear the textarea, press 1, go deposit then enter, it deposits $2 instead! if I do that again it will deposit $3!

Comment: Where do you clear it?

Comment: I have a button clear that sets my textarea to "", I'm editing my code above and adding that bit. Thanks

Comment: I recommend you to move `btnEnter.addActionListener...` out of `btnDeposit.addActionListener...`. I guess it adds a new actionlistener each time, so in the second try, you have 2 listeners for `btnDeposit` which add the money twice.

Comment: But I have another function which is Withdraw, if my enter button is outside deposit or withdrawn how would it know I'm depositing or withdrawing?

Comment: A quick and dirty fix would be to remove the last listener, before you add the new listener. A better approach would be to have one listener were you distinguish the events by e.g. the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is called out in the comment section. You are declaring multiple listeners which are calling the respective `deposit()` or `withdraw()` method every time you perform an action.

To avoid this. You can set one listener class to all of your buttons like this.

Create an inner class

```
private class MySpecialListener implements ActionListener{

@Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
               if(e.getSource == btnDesposit) // do stuff and so on
            }

}
```

and add the listener like this

```
MySpecialListener myListener = new MySpecialListener();
btnDeposit.addActionListener(myListener);
```

---

The above requires you to re-write your code, but it has a better structure then your current one.
To fix your current problem you can remove the last listener like this:

```
for(ActionListener al : btnEnter.getActionListeners())
 btnEnter.removeActionListener(al)

btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //convert text area into double
            double depositNumber = Double.parseDouble(ta.getText());
            sav.deposit(depositNumber);
            btnWithdraw.setEnabled(true);
            btnBalance.setEnabled(true);
        }

    });
```

Comment: I don't get any of that, I can't create a private class that implements Actions listener it says illegal start of expression... then I can't access my btnDeposit from inside there it suggests me to create a local variable btnDeposit?

Comment: @Gui The inner class is inside your current class. Inside the brackets. The declaration and initialization of that goes into your main class. As I said you have to re-write your structure if you want to use that. A quick an dirty fix without all that is in my bottom post.

Comment: Yeah okay, I'll get in contact with my teacher on how to re structure my code based on your answer. The quick and dirty fix works like a charm tho, thank you!